# How to replace the second match without replacing the entire line

Tags: sed

I have a host file with the below lines:

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.1.1  servername
```

The  server IP is : 192.168.1.1    which is represented by the IP variable below:

```
IP=192.168.1.1
```

I want to replace the second entry that starts with 127.0 with $IP i.e:

instead of :

```
127.0.1.1  servername
```

it should be :

```
192.168.1.1 servername
```

I tried to use the below sed statement :

```
sed  "0,/127.0.*/! s/127.0.*/$IP/" /etc/hosts
```

But its replacing the entire line  removing the servername as well ,and leave me with :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost

192.168.1.1
```

its should be :

```
192.168.1.1 servername
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `.` is a regex-active character, you need to escape it with a backslash (`\`),
2. `.*` will match everything until EOL, use a negated character class for matching everything until first blank character instead.

```
sed '0,/^127\.0\./! s/^127\.0\.[^[:blank:]]*/'"$IP"'/' file
```

Btw, you could get this task done way more safely&robustly using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ awk -v IP="$IP" 'n<2 && index($1,"127.0.")==1 && ++n==2 { $1=IP } 1' file
127.0.0.1
192.168.1.1 servername
```

Comment: Both of the answers will do the trick ,but will not keep the same number of spaces between 192.168.1.1 to servername , i need the space between those words to be 4 spaces